# Pull request between two repos that do not have a fork connection, but are related

Tags: github, git-fork

Basically, I have forked a GitHub repo, repo B, which is an old version of repo A with some new additions. Except, the author cloned repo A and made the new additions locally, then uploaded the repo to Github, so there is no fork connection between A and B. I want to pull the latest repo A code into my fork, which is repo C, but can't. How could I resolve this?

I've tried to find answers, but all I can find says it is basically impossible.